# auto return immediately(without 10 sec) to our website after Paypal transaction completed

Tags: paypal

I world like to know how can I make a PayPal transaction, and let the user auto return to our website immediately (no waiting for 10 seconds)?

Is there any solution?

Comment: Have you tried anything? share some of what you have done so far..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Paypal return link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13988431/paypal-return-link)

Comment: finally, I'm using the paypal rest  api for the task and solve it!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know, PayPal didn't provide any option to reduce or get rid the waiting time (10 sec) on PayPal confirmation page. Unless buyer manually clicks on redirect link on that page to return to your website.